# How to combine Two Columns from Tables And take that result to a Drop down

Tags: sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu

I have a table `table1` with column A holding values

```
ORD26
ORD27
ORD28
```

I have a second table `table2` with column B holding values

```
21/10/2011
22/10/2011
25/10/2011
```

I want the result as

```
ORD26-21/10/2011
ORD27-22/10/2011
ORD28-25/10/2011
```

I need to take this value to a drop down list ..

How can I do this?

Comment: How are `table1` and `table2` connected? What common column do they have to join them together?? Without a common column - how can you know which rows from each table to join together??

Comment: Both the tables hav a common column..so that we can Join them

Comment: Letzz suppose Both Tables Have a Column name 'order_ID In common

Comment: `SELECT  a.A + ' - ' + b.B
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.order_ID = a.order_ID`

Comment: The data types nvarchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.
So what can i do in this case,as my column holds an nvarchar and datetime datatypes

Comment: @Lijina - You use `CAST or `CONVERT` on the date type like marc_s posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two tables have a common column `order_id`, and your column in `table2` is a `DATETIME`, then use this query:

```
SELECT
  t1.A + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), t2.B, 103)
FROM dbo.Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
```

The "style" of your converted datetime column is controlled by the `CONVERT` function in T-SQL - read all about it on [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx)